# AirDatepicker, как в поле Input вывести день недели?

Tags: javascript

```js
new AirDatepicker('.datepicker', {
    inline: false,
    position: 'bottom right',
    autoClose: true,
    dateFormat(date) {
        return date.toLocaleString('ru', {
            day: '2-digit',
            month: 'long',            
        });
    } 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <input readonly class="datepicker"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

нашел ответ на свой же вопрос. может кому понадобится
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat

надо добавить в опции

```js
weekday: 'long'
```